# AWS - Assign an IAM profile based on a Mapping lookup in CF template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

In my Cloud Formation template I have IAM Mappings for different environments:

```
Mappings:
  EnvironmentToIAMInstanceProfileARN:
    dev:
      Profile: [ "arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/AnInstanceProfile" ]
    test:
      Profile: [ "arn:aws:iam::0000000001:role/AppServerInstanceProfile", 
                  "arn:aws:iam::0000000001:role/AppProvisioningRole"]
```

I'm creating an S3 bucket and need to provide the Principal the IAM Profile:

```
 AppS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3NameParam
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: 'Restrict access to the IAM Instance ARN'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*' # !FindInMap [EnvironmentToIAMInstanceProfileARN, !Ref 'EnvType', Profile]
            Action: 
              - 's3:GetBucketAcl'
              - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
              - 's3:PutObject'
            Resource:
              - !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                  - !Ref S3NameParam
                  - ''
              - !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                  - !Ref S3NameParam
                  - /*
```

If I assign **'*'**  to Prinicpal it works, however I'm trying to look up the mapping:

```
Principal: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToIAMInstanceProfileARN, !Ref 'EnvType', Profile]
```

This doesn't work and results in error:

> Invalid bucket policy syntax. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; 
>   Error Code: MalformedPolicy;

Does anyone know how I can do this, or why it fails?

ps The EnvType Parameter does exist:

```
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Description: Environment Name
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:  [dev, test, prod]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article the syntax needs to have Service.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

JSON:

```
 "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
          "datapipeline.amazonaws.com"
        ]
```

However, following some other documentation I worked out its AWS not Service:

JSON:

```
  "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
          "datapipeline.amazonaws.com"
        ]
```

Solution in YAML:

```
  Principal:
     AWS: 
       !FindInMap [EnvironmentToIAMInstanceProfileARN, !Ref 'EnvType', Profile]
```